# Can't open dmg for combo update to 10.14: corrupt image

Tags: macos, mojave

I've downloaded `macOSUpdCombo10.14.6.dmg` from [the official apple site](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2010?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) twice now in order to update my 10.10 to 10.14, both times when I try to open the dmg I am told that it can't be opened as the image is corrupt.

I'm at a loss, this isn't happening with other dmg files I have, I've run the `disk utility` function `verify` on my drive and it reports no errors. 
 Is it the file? Am I doing something wrong?  Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't upgrade 10.10.y to 10.14.6 with macOSUpdCombo10.14.6. The combo updater is meant to update 10.14.x (with x=0-5) to 10.14.6!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get [macOS Mojave](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT210190) directly from the App Store and install it. This will give you the most recent version of 10.14.6, you won't need to run the combo updater afterwards.

Comment: I know that this doesn't explain the corrupted image issue, but there is no gain in analyzing that because you won't be able to use it's content anyway.

Comment: So the problem I'm facing is that the app store only lets me upgrade to 10.15.X, which is incompatible with my software.  Any attempts to download a version of 10.14.X from their site leaves me with a corrupt dmg.  I can't seem to come up with a way to get from 10.10 to 10.14...

Comment: @MichaelHackman What happens when you try do download Mojave from the store via the link?

Comment: Wow, I'm dumb.  Your link worked perfectly, totally didn't think to even click it.  Thanks for the nudge there

Comment: You don't need the combo updater afterwards, but you _do_ need the security updates! After the one year mark, those additional security releases aren't rolled in. Of course, macOS will prompt you.